# Show option in second Select2 dropdown based on first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to show only options in the second dropdown (child) attribute data-value based on first dropdown value (parent) after change, and hide the rest of options.

```js
$('.custom_select').select2()

$('select[name=parent]').on('change', function(){
  // show only options from child equals to this.val()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="custom_select" name="parent">
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="2">example 2</option>
  <option value="3">example 3</option>
</select>
<select class="custom_select" name="child">
  <option data-value="1">child 1</option>
  <option data-value="1">child 1</option>
  <option data-value="2">child 2</option>
  <option data-value="3">child 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get value of first select box and then compare it with `option` of second select box depending on that hide or show options i.e :

```js
$('.custom_select').select2()

$('select[name=parent]').on('change', function() {
  //getting value
  var val = $(this).val();
  //looping through options
  $('select[name=child] option').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.attr("data-value") == val) {
      //if the option have that values show option
      $("select[name=child] option[data-value='" + val + "']").prop('disabled', false);

    } else {
      //other options which don't have selected value hide them
      $("select[name=child] option:not(:contains('" + val + "'))").prop('disabled', true);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="custom_select" name="parent">
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="2">example 2</option>
  <option value="3">example 3</option>
</select>
<select class="custom_select" name="child">
  <option data-value="1">child 1</option>
  <option data-value="2">child 2</option>
  <option data-value="3">child 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This answer is decent and clean works in the snippet above , Thank you!
but when i tried it in my project, it just worked on the last option of parent. ihad to take the line of disabled, false out of if, else statement, i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#child").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
    $('select').select2({ width: '100%', placeholder: "Select an Option", allowClear: true });
})

function setOption() {
    var id=$("#parent").val();
    $('#child').select2('destroy');
        $("#child").children('option').hide();
        $("#child").children("option[data-value^=" +id + "]").show();
        $('#child').select2({ width: '100%', placeholder: "Select an Option", allowClear: true });
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>




<select class="custom_select" name="parent" id="parent" onchage=setOption()>
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="2">example 2</option>
  <option value="3">example 3</option>
</select>
<select class="custom_select" name="child" id="child">
  <option data-value="1">child 1</option>
  <option data-value="1">child 1</option>
  <option data-value="2">child 2</option>
  <option data-value="3">child 3</option>
</select>
```